# python using self in decorators in class with kwarg

Tags: python, class, decorator, python-decorators

So I have this set of code, testing decorator `base_permissions_check`:

```
def authenticated(self,*arg,**kwargs):
    function_call = inspect.stack()[1][4][0].strip()
    matched = re.match('^self\.', function_call)
    if not matched:
        raise Exception("function is private")

    return self.user.is_authenticated()

def base_permissions_check(func):
    def wrap(self,**kwargs):

        if not self.authenticated(kwargs):
            return self.permissions
            # func(kwargs)
        return func(kwargs)
    return wrap

#public
@base_permissions_check
def has_video_permission(self,**kwargs):
```

The error says that `authenticated() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` when I call has_video_permission. I really don't know what's wrong? while I pass only one kwarg into it

Comment: The first argument is `self`. `kwargs` is the second.

Comment: but authenticated accept self and **kwargs, what's wrong?

Comment: You might be looking for [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: still the same error

Comment: Please add the **full traceback** of the error to your question so we don't have to keep guessing as to what exactly is complaining here.

Comment: If you need a way of creating robust decorators that can work with either normal functions or methods of classes, you may be better off using the ``wrapt`` package. http://wrapt.readthedocs.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrapped `func()` function is not bound to the instance as a method, so you need to pass in `self` explicitly. You also need to apply the `kwargs` dictionary as separate keyword arguments using the `**kwargs` call syntax:

```
return func(self, **kwargs)
```

Your `authenticated` method is not actually *using* the `kwargs` dictionary you pass in, so you could just call `self.authenticated()`, but if you need to have access to those keyword arguments, you probably want to use the `**kwargs` call syntax there too:

```
if not self.authenticated(**kwargs):
```

Since you see the error when you *call* the decorated function, you are probably passing in a *positional* argument, but your wrapper only accepts *keyword arguments* (beyond `self`). Perhaps you want to add `*args` to handle those positional arguments:

```
def base_permissions_check(func):
    def wrap(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if not self.authenticated(**kwargs):
            return self.permissions
            # func(kwargs)
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrap

#public
@base_permissions_check
def has_video_permission(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
```

Comment: Then please provide the **full traceback** of the error in your question. You have more problems than just the one I pointed out in that case.

Comment: Just realize I need to restart the server to see the changes get affected. That's why it keeps prompting the old error.

Comment: are we able to make decorator within the instance? means to use self

Comment: @LeDuyKhanh: the decorator applies to the *function*, and the result is added to the class object once the class body is complete. Function objects then act as [*descriptors*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), which means they produce a method, bound to the instance, when looked up on an instance. So your `wrap` function is bound as a method and has `self` passed in, but the original `func` function is not, so you have to pass in `self` explicitly.